# animation on objects with the same class, one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

im trying to run an animation hover effect on all elements on a page. my problem is, when i hove over any of them, it animates them all.

```
$('div.anime').hover( function() {
$('.box').animate({'do something cool'});
});
```

All of the boxes have the same class `anime`. So im just trying to figure out how to only animate when you hover over one, with out giving them all separate classes you know?

I know this is a simple question, but im still learning the ways of jQuery :) so please bear with me

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="anime">

<div class="box">Hey show me! Im cool!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show a portion of your HTML that includes at least one `div.anime` and `.box`?

Comment: hah! i guessed correctly on your html setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally Speaking they way you would accomplish this would be to use the `this` keyword to specify the item being hovered, and then choose the DOM element you want to animate in relation to `this` by traversing the DOM tree.

example

given the following HTML

```
<div class="anime">

    <p>other stuff</p>

    <div class="box">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

This javascript (using jQuery) would select and animate only the `.box` contained within the hovered upon `.anime` because I'm using the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to traverse the DOM in relation to `$(this)` (the element that was hovered).

```
$('div.anime').hover( function() {
    $(this).find('.box').animate({'do something cool'});
});
```

You can read more and find more functions for [Traversing the DOM here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Answer (score 2):

try using function each of jquery

```
$( "div.anime" ).each(function(){

$(this).hover( function() {
   $(this).find('.box').animate({'do something cool'});
});

});
```

Comment: ah so this is the `.each` you were talking about, i think i was looking at another jQuery each...the WRONG each lol

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can capture the target of an event with 'this'. Using 'this' will restrict the animate method to the object being acted on.

```
$('div.anime').hover(function(e){
   $(this).animate({'do something cool'});

}, function(){
   // dont forget on mouseout
   $(this).animate({'return to normal state'});

})
```

Comment: ah and the funny thing is i forgot to post that part lol, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.anime .box').hover( function() {
$(this).animate({'do something cool'});
});
```